# Avoid cutting the correct file - it must follow

Tags: css, svg

It's the case that my svg does not follow down or to the side if my code has a greater value than stated.

As you can see in the picture here, it's color color like stop at the maximum limit of the file.

How would I like it to do, for example, to follow it where it ends?

[image: svg file]

Here, as I show in the picture, it should look when it is.

[image: svg file 2]

html code:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 (200*100+1%) (250*100+1%)" width="200" height="250">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="180" height="170" style="fill:none;stroke:#7FFF00;stroke-width:5;"></rect>
<rect x="15" y="120" width="140" height="125" style="fill:none;stroke:#D2691E;stroke-width:5;"></rect>
</svg>
```

It must also follow if the green color goes to the side. It should in no way like just cut the rect area of the specified color.

Is it something with viewport or how? The specified values for height and length are based on a code that I have in my java file.

Comment: It is to do with either viewbox or the height of the actual svg tag so because 170+125 (height of inner elements) is greater than 250 (height of svg)

Comment: A very simple solution would be using `svg{overflow:visible;}` in your CSS. Also: the `viewBox` 
 value is not valid. If you need to do something line this you need to do it in Javascript.

Comment: @PatrickSturm what u mean?
@enxaneta u mean: `<svg width="200" height="250" style="overflow:scroll;"><rect x="0" y="0" width="180" height="170" style="fill:none;stroke:#7FFF00;stroke-width:5;"></rect><rect x="15" y="120" width="140" height="325" style="fill:none;stroke:#D2691E;stroke-width:5;"></rect></svg>`